# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) ([Errno 13] Permission denied)")

Tags: sqlalchemy, pymysql, operationalerror

I'm trying to connect to mysql using below

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@localhost/test")
connection = engine.connect()
```

it works while in local and when deployed the code in one of our linux box , am getting

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx' ([Errno 13] Permission denied)")

I checked the user privileges and the user has all the necessary privileges.

using the same user and am able to connect from python terminal from the same linux box but it doesnt work using the python code.

Any suggestions if am missing anything?

Comment: Are you using the *exact same* credentials (username and password) when connecting to the two different machines?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

The issue was the http network connect policy was disabled for apache and it worked when we enabled it.